# WebClient read content of error page

Tags: c#, .net

i have an application that loads the page content. I use the WebClient class. I need to retrieve the contents even when the server returns an error such as 404, 500, ...
I need something like this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string pageContent;
try {
    pageContent = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/page");
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    pageContent = ex.Response.PageContent; // <-- I need this
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string pageContent;
try {
    pageContent = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/page");
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Stream receiveStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( receiveStream, encode );
    pageContent=readStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```